# Perfil de Identidade IIS aliados a aplicações do sistema operacional

Tags: php, laravel, windows, iis

Desenvolvo uma funcionalidade para uma aplicação PHP/Laravel multi-tenant hospedada em ambiente Windows/IIS, que faz uso das filas tradicionais do Laravel. O desafio nessa funcionalidade, devido ao ambiente limitado do Windows e a impossibilidade de utilizarmos outras tecnologias, devido a aplicação já estar produção, era o de poder ter um controle/gerenciamento sobre as filas, de modo que possibilitasse um inicio/reinicio automático, e caso necessário, que fosse possível escalar.

Basicamente uma das alternativas mais viáveis, era o uso do Agendador de Tarefas, de modo que pudessemos iniciar o "php artisan queue...." via tarefa. Tivemos alguns problemas com as permissões padrão do IIS, e conseguimos contornar, colocando a identidade da pool como LocalSystem.

Gostaria de saber sobre as implicações, e se há alguma forma alternativa ao uso do LocalSystem para trabalhar com esse recurso do Sistema operacional, sem prejudicar o funcionamento da funcionalidade(erros com permissão, etc...)?